# "DOM Exception 18" from canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

I'm taking an SVG image, drawing it onto a canvas, and trying to export it via toDataURL, but Chrome is throwing me that DOM Exception 18 security error.  I know the problem is because I drew the SVG image onto the canvas with a data URI scheme (data:image/svg+xml;base64), so I guess the browser sees it as cross-domain (i.e., a security problem), but I can't think of any other way to get my SVG stuff onto the canvas.  I can't host it because the SVG contents are dynamic and manipulated first before needing to be exported via toDataURL.

I read through some of the other similar questions asked on here but couldn't find any solutions for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome drawing *any* SVG on to a `canvas` taints it because the SVG *might* contain a `foreignObject`, [here is the bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68568).  Chrome also has issues with [data URI schemes and `canvas`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58999), so you're running into a double whammy.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. As a workaround I used a [SVG to HTML5 Canvas Converter](http://www.professorcloud.com/svg-to-canvas/) to transpile the svg into canvas calls.