# Convert Svg to Png on Client Side

Tags: javascript, html, image, svg

I am working on a Web based application where user can create designs in Svg. i want to convert the svg design into png image file on client side. i found a solution of using canvas, this works well in firefox, but in chrome it generate security error.

check the code below thanks:-

```
 var mainsvg=document.getElementById('svgforImg');                           
 var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');                       
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        var data=mainsvg.innerHTML;
                        var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
                        var svg = new Blob([data], {
                                type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"
                        });
                        var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
                        var img = new Image();
 img.onload = function() {
                               ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                                DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);                                  
                                var imageurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
```

Now my variable imageurl contains 'base64 png' image. this works in Firefox. But in chrome line

```
var imageurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

generate security error.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["DOM Exception 18" from canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829525/dom-exception-18-from-canvas)

Comment: So it means, i have to move on server side to get image converted both for chrome and firefox

Comment: Yes, probably (unless you can require the latest dev version of chrome). If the svg is simple enough you may have some luck with e.g canvg - http://code.google.com/p/canvg/.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390232/why-does-canvas-todataurl-throw-a-security-exception). From which server does the SVG originate? If it is a different one than the one your application is coming from (remember: sub-domains matter!), you could add the desired http-headers in the originating server.

Comment: as you can see on code, SVG is in DOM. same place, where canvas is created